# how do I make my page cover the full width

Tags: html, css

It never happenned to me, but there is a small blank space on the right, what could it be?

https://github.com/LeandroMore1/Talleres-Merida-Galicia

https://leandromore1.github.io/Talleres-Merida-Galicia/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines to your CSS:

1.

```
body { 
  ...
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

2. 

```
header {
  ...
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Setting overflow-x: hidden; in body does not solve the problem with overflowing element, just hides it. That header part of it is accurate if the goal was to make the background image full size.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with classes cuerpoHeader, row is not wrapped in bootstrap container and is overflowing and thus stretching the page. If you wrap it inside of

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

the problem will disappear

Comment: Thank you so much!! the gap reduced, but still there is a tiny almost imperceptible gap, what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the Background Image? As there looks to be a gap on the right where the image isn't showing.

Assuming this...

Basically

1. Make your image bigger (like 2000px wide as that tends to cover most monitors, excluding larger things like TVs)
2. Add to your CSS `background-position: center` then that is probably going to cover you for the majority of use cases

If what I've said above isn't what you're looking for. Basically apply this CSS to the relevant section of the page `width:100%` and that will cover off the majority of weird issues.